# populating value of textbox by adding dynamic texboxes

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I'm attempting to add all textboxes that are dynamically generated to get a subtotal.

here is my code that generates the boxes:

```
<table id="billing-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Service</th><th>Price</th><th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <?PHP
             $aService = $_POST['service'];
             $N = count($aService);


         for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
         {
              $services=MYSQLI_QUERY($con, "SELECT * FROM `Service` WHERE Service_ID = '$aService[$i]'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
              $getservices = mysqli_fetch_array($services);
              $serviceid = $getservices['Service_ID'];
              $servicedesc = $getservices['Service_Type'];
              $serviceprice = $getservices['Service_Cost'];
      echo'<tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="service" value="'. $servicedesc. '"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price'.$i.'" value="'. $serviceprice. '"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="'. $serviceprice. '"></td>

           </tr>';
    } ?>


            <tr>
                <td style="position:absolute;left:5%;">Subtotal</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="total" value=""></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

I'm attempting to use jquery to do this based off of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LJKjR/478/

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('input.qty').change(function() {   

    // Loop through all input's and re-calculate the total
    var total = 0;
    $('input.qty').each(function(){
        total += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    // Update the total
    $('#total').val(total);
});
    </script>
</head>
```

I have everything in place with no errors, but no total value of all prices combined in my subtotal textbox? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: how many rows generated.each row have total box?

Comment: Okay, so I've found that if I modify the text qty text inputs after the page loads, the subtotal calculates. I need it to do it on the fly without the need to click and modify the input box. Also its not showing me number format. So when my page loads and I have 2 services selected at 19.99 a piece, I'm showing a subtotal of 38 not 39.98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your script inside document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // Commenting the below line because you want in on the fly
    //$('input.qty').change(function() {  

        // Loop through all input's and re-calculate the total
        var total = 0;
        $('input.qty').each(function(){
            total += parseInt(this.value);
        });

        // Update the total
        $('#total').val(total);


    //});

});
```

And if you want the decimals too, then you should use **parseFloat** instead if parseInt.

Comment: Ive done this but it still does not calculate until I modify the number in the input box. ALso I'm not receiving the total with my decimal. its completely ignoring the decimal and the numbers after total ex 19.99 its only seeing 19....but even with doc ready function its not updating until i modify the number before the decimal

Comment: Hi Kenny, I have modified the answer above. Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you are calculating on the `change` event which will ofcourse fire only on change. Instead remove the change function and wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

As for the decimal value, it's not being preserved because while calculating total, you are converting it into `int` with `parseInt()`. Instead use **[parseFloat().](http://jsfiddle.net/594n4/)**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/594n4/)**